# File deletion under special conditions, recursively if possible

Tags: rm, recursive

I am looking for a unix command sequence, which is able to perform a quite complex, conditional deleting action.

All files with the extensions "[NAME].cut" and "[NAME].cut.bak" shall be deleted, IF there exists no corresponding file named "[NAME].rec" or "[NAME].mpg" in the same folder.

The command shall be run on an integrated device with some minimal kernel, and therefore not use "special tools".
e.g. 'ls' and 'rm' can be used, 'find' is not present (i.e. only via an external tool, which I would prefer not to depend on)

If possible, the command shall delete recursively in subdirectories as well...

Background is following:
I am developing a tool for a Linux-based PVR, that allows cutting of recorded programmes. For each recording (extension .rec or .mpg) the segment markers are stored in a .cut-file. When some recording gets moved/renamed/deleted, then the corresponding cut-file remains on the disk useless.
I already have implemented the removing of those useless cut-files in C. But I am wondering, whether there may be a (simple) system based solution. In this case it could be run via 'system' and & in the background, which would make my application more responsive...

Here are the commands, which are included within the PVR's firmware:

affinity, arp, awk, basename, bash, busybox, cat, chgrp, chmod, chown, cmp, cp, cramfsck, cut, date, dd, df, dirname, dmesg, du, echo, egrep, env, expr, false, fgrep, flash_erase, flash_eraseall, flash_info, free, getty, grep, head, hexdump, hostname, id, ifconfig, install, kill, killall, ln, logger, login, ls, md5sum, mkcramfs, mkdir, mknod, mktemp, more, mount, mv, nice, norcleanmark, od, passwd, pidof, ping, pmtest, portmap, printenv, printf, ps, pwd, readlink, renice, rm, rmdir, route, sed, seq, sh, shutdown, sleep, sort, strings, stty, sync, tail, tee, telnet, tftp, time, tinylogin, touch, tr, true, tty, twin, umount, uname, uniq, usleep, vi, wc, which, whoami, xargs, yes

Do you have any tips for me?

Comment: Which are the extensions to be deleted? `[NAME].cut` and `[NAME].cut.bak` or `.cut` and `.cut.bak`? Also if there exists **no** corresponding file with extension `[NAME].rec` or `[NAME.mpg]`?

Comment: The extensions are '.cut' and '.cut.bak'. For example, if there are the files 'a.mpg', 'a.cut', 'b.cut', 'c.cut.bak', 'd.cut.bak', 'd.rec', then only 'b.cut' and 'c.cut.bak' shall be deleted.

Comment: What is the actual use case? What is the embedded device? (How much RAM, what kind of "disk": SD cards?) How would that command be started? Thru some web interface? How are by what programs are the `.cut`  & `.rec` files created? It might be some [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so you really should **edit your question** to improve it (and give motivations and more context)

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't keep this simpler; this works but **it assumes there are no files whose filename contains newlines in the target directory**; first test the command using this:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.cut" -o -name "*.cut.bak" \) -exec bash -c '[ -f "$(<<< "{}" sed "s/\(.*\/[^.]*\).*/\1/").rec" -o -f "$(<<< "{}" sed "s/\(.*\/[^.]*\).*/\1/").mpg" ] && echo "{}"' \;
```

If the files listed are those expected to be deleted, you can go ahead and run this:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.cut" -o -name "*.cut.bak" \) -exec bash -c '[ -f "$(<<< "{}" sed "s/\(.*\/[^.]*\).*/\1/").rec" -o -f "$(<<< "{}" sed "s/\(.*\/[^.]*\).*/\1/").mpg" ] && rm "{}"' \;
```

Test on a directory hierarchy created ad hoc:

```
~/tmp$ tree
.
└── dir1
    ├── file1.cut
    ├── file1.cut.bak
    ├── file1.rec
    ├── file2.cut
    ├── file2.cut.bak
    ├── file2.mpg
    ├── file3.cut
    ├── file3.cut.bak
    └── subdir1
        ├── file1.cut
        ├── file1.cut.bak
        ├── file1.rec
        ├── file2.cut
        ├── file2.cut.bak
        ├── file2.mpg
        ├── file3.cut
        └── file3.cut.bak

2 directories, 16 files
~/tmp$ find . -type f \( -name "*.cut" -o -name "*.cut.bak" \) -exec bash -c 'if [ -f "$(<<< "{}" sed "s/\(.*\/[^.]*\).*/\1/").rec" -o -f "$(<<< "{}" sed "s/\(.*\/[^.]*\).*/\1/").mpg" ]; then rm "{}"; fi' \;
~/tmp$ tree
.
└── dir1
    ├── file1.rec
    ├── file2.mpg
    ├── file3.cut
    ├── file3.cut.bak
    └── subdir1
        ├── file1.rec
        ├── file2.mpg
        ├── file3.cut
        └── file3.cut.bak

2 directories, 8 files
```

As you can see, all files with extension `.cut` or `.bak` for which a file with the same name and extension `.rec` or `.mpg` exists are deleted recursively (`file1.cut` and `file1.cut.bak` are deleted because of `file1.rec`, `file2.cut` and `file2.cut.bak` are deleted because of `file2.mpg`; `file3.cut` and `file3.cut.bak` are not deleted because there's no `file3.rec` or `file3.mpg` in the same directory)

Comment: Just two examples, that go wrong: './-Das Korallendreieck 1/Das Korallendreieck 1.cut' and 'Forrest Gump.cut' shall be removed, but in both cases the corresponding '.rec' file is present.

Comment: @chris86 I think you have to wait some minutes for the global rep to update network-wise, however let me get this straight, those are the only two files that are not working? Or it's a sample? If the first, are you sure they're named exactly the same but the extension? Try to run `ls file1 | hexdump -C` and `ls file2 | hexdump -C`, see if they match in everything but the extensions and if the extensions don't contain extra characters

Comment: Got the code to work now. But there is a problem, when a file name contains a '.' (dot) before the extension. Those files will be falsely deleted...

Comment: @chris86 What was wrong with it? Anyway the dot problem *should* be easily solvable, try switching both `sed`s' inner command to this one: `s/\(.*\/.*\)\..*/\1/`

Comment: I explained in the chat: '-e' does not find any files that are larger than 4 GB... To the dot problem: No. With the latest modification of sed, it always removes the '.cut.bak' file, even if there is a '.rec' present. -> I don't understand this cryptical sed-syntax - but maybe a fix encoding of "name ends with the string '.cut' or '.cut.bak' would be better?

Comment: @chris86 So that was it, simply the file size? No the cryptic syntax is needed regardless, here it's more complicated because you need to match the full paths output of find, and now I grok from your comment that the new problem is that sometimes the file has 2 extensions, that's why it doesn't work (and it's going to be more cryptic). Let me see if it can be done with `sed`, in the meantime do you have either GNU `grep` or Perl installed? Either of those would greatly help in this.

Comment: No chance for Perl. But grep seems to be present:BusyBox v1.11.1 (2014-03-06 17:37:46 KST) multi-call binary

Usage: grep [-HhrilLnqvsoeFEABC] PATTERN [FILEs...]

Search for PATTERN in each FILE or standard input

Comment: But would it not be the simplest solution to just compare the last 4 (resp. 8) characters of the string for a match of ".cut" or ".cut.bak"?

Comment: @chris86 No, because that's not what `sed` it's doing, `sed` it's stripping the extension from the path and the string following the subshell enclosing `sed` is appending a different extension, for the following `-f` test, so stripping the extension is needed somehow, the only possible simplification AFAIK would be using `bash` parameter expansion, but the new condition (an optional double extension) I think rules that out. Anyway I've found a way of doing it with `sed`: `sed -r 's/(.*).cut(.bak)?$/\1/'`

Comment: DeleteCuts.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `'s/(.'
DeleteCuts.sh: line 1: `find . -type f \( -name "*.cut" -o -name "*.cut.bak" \) -exec bash -c '[ -f "$(echo "{}" | sed -r 's/(.*\/.*).cut(.bak)?$/\1/').rec.inf"
 -o -f "$(echo "{}" | sed -r 's/(.*\/.*).cut(.bak)?$/\1/'.mpg.inf" ] || echo "{}
"' \;'

Comment: @chris86 Forgot that was in single quotes already: `sed -r "s/(.*).cut(.bak)?$/\1/"` (shortened from the previous version)

Comment: Seems to work now. Thank you very very much!!! But the part where the sed is inserted is also already in double quotes - isn't this a problem? And what if the filename contains a quotation mark?

Comment: @chris86 Unescaped double-quotes in subshells are not a problem, so that's not a problem, however the double-quote in the filename... that could be a problem. Not sure how to deal with this. I'm actually asking a question, because I think no matter how do you escape it that's gonna break the command.

Answer (score 0):

If the command is to be run on some small embedded device with very limited commands and shells (e.g. missing `find`, minimal shell à la `sash`), a possible approach would be to write some tiny C (or perhaps C++) program doing that, and compile that program to an executable (it would be nice to make that program a free software).

You'll use [nftw](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html) to recursively traverse the file tree, and build an array (or a vector, or a list) of paths to be removed. Then a second pass would effectively remove the files.  Relevant functions are [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) (to traverse the file tree), [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) (to construct file names), [access(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) (to test existence of file), [stat(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) (to get type, size and other meta-data about a file), [remove(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/remove.3.html) (to remove a file), [basename(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html), etc.

If you have GNU `find`, you might make a shell script with it (but details could depend upon your actual shell, especially if it is small enough to not be POSIX compliant). Collect the filenames to be deleted in some temporary file. Then remove them later.

If you insist on using shell solutions, and assuming that GNU find is available, you might have several shell scripts:

First, a shell script (invoked from outside), let's name it `clean-the-mess.sh` which would create a temporary file, then invoke another internal shell script `consider-cleaning.sh` for every `.cut` & `.cut.bak`  file:

```
#!/bin/sh
## untested clean-the-mess.sh script
## a temporary file listing files to remove
cleanlistfile=$(tempfile -s .cleanlist)
## on exit, or SIGQUIT, SIGTERM, or SIGINT signal, remove it
trap "rm $cleanlistfile" EXIT QUIT TERM INT
## find every file name .cut | .cut.bak; run consider-cleaning.sh on it
find -type f \( -name '*.cut' -o 'name '*.cut.bak' \) \
    -exec consider-cleaning.sh '{}' $cleanlistfile \;
## remove the collected file list
for f in $(cat $cleanlistfile) ; do rm $f ; done
```

<sup>That won't work if some files have spaces in their name. Perhaps consider [xargs(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)</sup>

Then you need to code the internal `consider-cleaning.sh`  script, which adds file paths to the list of files to be cleaned. It could be

```
#!/bin/sh
# internal untested consider-cleaning.sh script
file=$1
collectlist=$2
case $file in 
 *.cut) 
   bas=$(basename $file .cut)
   if [ ! -f "$bas.rec" -a ! -f "$bas.mpg" ]; then
      echo $file >> $collectlist
   fi
 ;;
 *.cur.bak)
   bas=$(basename $file .cut.bak)
   if [ ! -f "$bas.rec" -a ! -f "$bas.mpg" ]; then
      echo $file >> $collectlist
   fi
 ;;
 esac
```

My scripts are not proven, untested, so are probably wrong. Put `#!/bin/sh -vx` as their first line to test & debug them (you'll get some execution trace)

Alternatively, embed a tiny [Lua](http://lua.org/) interpreter with the few basic primitive file related operations, and write your script in Lua. Lua is very easily embeddable, and can be made to be a tiny interpreter.